# How i can make div cover the object tag on html for IE11？

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make div cover the object tag `on HTML for IE11`, object tag is `activeX` for IE.

I **want to make div layer cover the object tag**.

Comment: Update your question with what you have so far and we'll try assist you with how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to wrap your object tag in a container `div`. Set the dimensions of the activex component on the container and set the containers `position` to `relative`.

Drop another `div` - as a sibling to your activex component, and set its `position` to `absolute`. This will allow it to float/start at the start of the container (just like your activex) by setting its `top` to 0. Set this `div`'s `height` and `width` to `100%` to fill the whole container. Since your container has the same dimensions that your activex, this should cover it up.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#object {
  height: 200px; /* emulate the objectx height */
  width: 200px; /* emulate the objectx width */
  background-color: yellow;
}

#overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="object"></div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/H405MbFN9a1wxzqXkYXz?p=preview

Play around with the Plunker to see what happens and learn how it works.